# What is this character ?

Tags: font, special-characters

I came across this character in a work-related document and I cannot understand what it is supposed to signify or even which language it is from. It is used in a grid and I am not sure if the presence of this character against a particular row is supposed to signify a positive or negative annotation.

## 

Here it is again. Take a good look and please tell me what this is.

**UPDATE:**

Here's what I am seeing. 
[image: screenshot_question]

Comment: Voting to close. Questions about implementation are off-topic on this site.

Comment: Is the character that you refer to a square? Or is it something else and it just looks like a square on this site because of rendering issues? Can you link to a screenshot of the character?

Comment: @VitalyMijiritsky Yes it is a square.  If you inspect the HTML is it a square.  If you copy paste into notepad it is a square.

Comment: @Blam Well, naturally it's a square here because it was recognized by the SE input mechanism as a square, and that's the only way SE can display it now. The question is whether it's what the OP really sees in his document (probably yes, but it can be amusing if it isn't).

Comment: @VitalyMijiritsky If OP was seeing something different in the document I would think he/she would have mentioned it.  But it is worth asking.  I get a square in notepad and copied it into my answer.  I have never had SE not render UNICODE as UNICODE.

Comment: @VitalyMijiritsky: Looks different to you? And does it interest you? :)

Comment: @Blam: Yes, I probably should have mentioned that I was seeing something spidery. I didn't realize that it might not render for everyone.

Comment: If you copy paste that character into notepad do you still get the spidery looking thing?  I suspect it has to do with how you PC renders UNICODE \uf050

Comment: @CodeNewbie Yes, it looks different, and I don't have any idea what it is.

Comment: @Blam: I work on Ubuntu 14.04 and I see the same spidery thing in gedit, Geany, Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: U+F050 is in the Unicode private use area, so it could be anything.

Answer (score 1):


It is a square
It is unicode \uf050
[Unicode Converter](https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter)

Some times that is the substitute character for character not found.
For example you are using ASCII.

Comment: Please see my update